# Атомарные операции при работе с файлами

Tags: unix

Есть два процесса и оба пишут в один файл в конец(открыт файл с модом O_APPEND). В случае одного процессора я понимаю что операция будет атомарна - нет угрозы прерывания процесса ядром. А что будет если я имею многоядерный процессор? Тут я абсолютно законно могу реально одновременно писать в этот файл из двух процессов и всякие атомарности мне тупо не помогут. Также отваливаются функции, которые превносят атомарность: pread & pwrite.

Вопрос: правильно ли я рассуждаю? Получается что разделять ресурс остаётся только при помощи семафоров?

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что в асинхронной ОС, один процесс с одним ядром на процессоре не нуждается в синхронизации?  А как же потоки?

Comment: А разделять можно не только семафорами. Кто запрещает мутексы? Вообще, любые средства из ipc пойдут

Comment: Да. Получается мой вопрос может отнести и к многопоточным вещам) просто рассмотрел два процесса.

Comment: Ну средства ipc я не рассматриваю сейчас. Вопрос в том, отваливаются ли плюшки атомарности функций pread pwrite и использование флага o_append?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5268578/4401952